# Android - Incoming SMS Listener (ICS)

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I have created a BroadcastReceiver, which actualy handles incoming SMS. this is code running fine in android 2.3.3 but somehow am not able to run the same code on devices running ICS.

My Receiver

```
public class SmsListener extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("#### SMS Received");
        if(intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")){
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();           //---get the SMS message passed in---
            SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
            String msg_from;
            if (bundle != null){
                //---retrieve the SMS message received---
                try{
                    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                    msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                    for(int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                        msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                        msg_from = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                        String msgBody = msgs[i].getMessageBody();
                        System.out.println("#### SMS Received: " + msg_from);
                        System.out.println("#### Message: " + msgBody);
                    }
                }catch(Exception e){
                           Log.d("Exception caught",e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Permissions

```
   <receiver android:name=".SmsListener" android:enabled="true"       android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS">
      <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
      </intent-filter>
   </receiver>    

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
```

Comment: You're not able to run this on ICS? Means it doesn't compile, deploy, log errors or it simply does not work? Did you take a look on LogCat's output?

Comment: Yes app is running perfectly fine on devices running 2.3 and below, but the same is not working on ICS devices, I saw the logs which indicates receiver is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i got the answer, with the latest security additions now android permits registration of  a broadcast receiver only through a visible activity.

Comment: Where is the reference ?